# Group events by date in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, sorting, ionic-framework, pipe

I've a problem here in Ionic 4 where I want to order some events by their date. I've read and it seems that with pipes I can achieve this, but Im not getting the idea how it works.

My json looks like this:

```
"clasesDB": [
        {
            "estado": true,
            "_id": "5d9a90b21c9d440000c41909",
            "horaApertura": "2019-10-18T13:00:00.363Z",
            "horaCierre": "2019-10-18T14:00:00.363Z",

        },
        {
            "estado": true,
            "_id": "5d9adca55d091800171a7e27",
            "horaApertura": "2019-10-18T18:00:00.363Z",
            "horaCierre": "2019-10-18T19:00:00.363Z",

        },
        {
            "estado": true,
            "_id": "5d9adc9b5d091800171a7e26",
            "horaApertura": "2019-10-19T19:00:00.363Z",
            "horaCierre": "2019-10-19T20:00:00.363Z",

        }
]
}
```

I want to filter them by 'horaApertura', so they can be something like this:

```
+--------------+
+ 2019-10-18   +
+--------------+
| First event  |
| Secondevent  |
+--------------+
+ 2018-10-19   +
+--------------+
| Second event |
+--------------+
+ x date       |
+--------------+
| x    event   |
+--------------+
```

Can you guys help me by getting the idea how I can do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any reason for unaccepting the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom pipe to group by date using [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'groupByDate'})
export class GroupByDate implements PipeTransform {

  transform(array) {
    let result = clasesDB.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      let item = acc.find(item => item.date === curr.horaApertura);

      if (item) {
        item.events.push(curr);
      } else {
        acc.push({
          "date": curr.horaApertura,
          "events": [curr]
        });
      }

      return acc;
    }, []); 

    return result;
  } 
}
```

Include this pipe as a declaration in a module.

And use it in your template as shown below:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of classesDB | groupByDate">
  <div>{{ item.date }}</div>
  <div *ngFor="let event of item.events>{{ event }}</div>
</div>
```

**Live example of grouping by date:**

```js
var clasesDB = [{ "estado": true, "_id": "5d9a90b21c9d440000c41909", "horaApertura": "2019-10-18T13:00:00.363Z", "horaCierre": "2019-10-18T14:00:00.363Z",

 }, { "estado": true, "_id": "5d9adca55d091800171a7e27", "horaApertura": "2019-10-18T18:00:00.363Z", "horaCierre": "2019-10-18T19:00:00.363Z",

 }, { "estado": true, "_id": "5d9adc9b5d091800171a7e26", "horaApertura": "2019-10-19T19:00:00.363Z", "horaCierre": "2019-10-19T20:00:00.363Z",

 },
 { "estado": true, "_id": "5d9adc9b5d091800171a7e28", "horaApertura": "2019-10-19T19:00:00.363Z", "horaCierre": "2019-10-19T20:00:00.363Z",

 } ];

let result = clasesDB.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let item = acc.find(item => item.date === curr.horaApertura);

  if (item) {
    item.events.push(curr);
  } else {
    acc.push({
      "date": curr.horaApertura,
      "events": [curr]
    });
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I have similar questions..can pls anw 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71442115/group-by-pipe-in-ionic-5-and-angular